# Quiero mostrar usuarios por ID y no automaticamente

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hay una sección en mi pagina que muestra (en un carrusel) una miniatura de distintos perfiles de usuario (limite 12)
Lo que quiero es decidir que usuarios mostrar, en vez de ordenarlos automáticamente por id de usuario, quiero mostrar los id's que yo decida

Aqui esta el codigo:

```
                    $this->db->limit($limit);
                $this->db->where('status','approved');
                $this->db->order_by("user_id", "desc");
                $users=$this->db->get('user')->result_array();
                foreach($users as $row){
```

Como podría hacer? 
Muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con ` ->where("id",$id_user)` where es a su vez and en laravel asi que puedes ir encadenando where solo cambia si quieres or que es orwhere

Comment: Gracias! Y como seria por ejemplo configurar para que muestre el user_id 12, 14 y 22?

Comment: @Bryro No entendi como seria el codigo entonces para configurar varios. Me podrias explicar un poco mas? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Es simple `WhereIn` y le pasas un arreglo de valores y el nombre de la columna

Comment: @Bryro Funciono!! Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podes usar [`where_in`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where_in)

```
$losID = array(12, 14, 22);
$this->db->where_in('user_id', $losID );
// Genera el SQL : WHERE user_id IN (12, 14, 22)
```

para ordenar por los ID del array podes probar construir un `ORDER BY FIELD`

```
$this->db
   ->protect_identifiers(FALSE)
   ->order_by('FIELD( user_id, '. implode(', ', $losID) .' )');
```

`protect_identifiers(FALSE)` evita que se le agreguen comillas a la expresión  `ORDER BY FIELD ( user_id, 12, 14, 22 )`

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Y como hago para que los muestre exactamente en el orden en el que esta?Quiero decir como: 22 25 21 en vez de: 21 22 25  como lo hace por defecto?